# How many different ways of choosing a committee of 4 individuals from 6 residents with at least one under the age of 7 .

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many different ways of choosing a committee of 4 individuals from 6 residents with at least one under the age of 7 (Show two different ways of solving this problem – think complements). There are 3 individuals under the age 7.

Comment: It is impossible to have no one under $7$, so $\binom{6}{4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these facts to build your case.

- There are $6$ residents, partitioned into: $3$ under-sevens and $3$ over-sevens.
- There are ${^6\mathrm C_4}$ ways to select $4$ from the $6$ residents in total.
- There are ${^3\mathrm C_k}~{^3\mathrm C_{4-k}}$ ways to select $k$ from $3$ under-sevens and $4-k$ from $3$ over-sevens for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$.

  *Notice:* You can not pick $0$ under-sevens as that would require picking 4 from 3 over-sevens; more than you have.